# Word Macro: Move line of text above previous line

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I am trying to use the following code to move a line of text that begins with "File #" above the previous line of text, but I get a bad parameter error on the Selection.Range.Move object.

```
For Each Paragraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Paragraph.Range.Select

    If InStr(Paragraph.Range.Text, "File #") Then
        Selection.Range.Move Unit = wdParagraph, Count:=-1
    Else
    End If
```

Here's a sample of the text:

Air Resources Board

File # 2019-1218-01

Zero-Emission Airport Shuttle Bus

Here's what I am trying to make it look like:

File # 2019-1218-01

Air Resources Board

Zero-Emission Airport Shuttle Bus

I need this to run through to the end of the document.

I admit my knowledge of VBA is rather limited (basically, I can do find/replace stuff easily, so this is out of my realm of understanding). Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

For Each Paragraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

```
If InStr(Paragraph.Range.Text, "File #") Then

    Paragraph.Range.Select
    Selection.Range.Relocate wdRelocateUp

End If
```

Next